# Qt - How to get the sidebar in MainWindow

Tags: qt

I amk new to qt. I tried to create a window with a widget. The widget contains a picture(a chess board). Now, If I tried to show the window it is showing a part of that picture. Here the code

```
#include<QApplication>
#include<QMainWindow>
#include<QWidget>
#include<QMenu>
#include<QMenuBar>
#include<QPainter>
#include<QFrame>
#include<QHBoxLayout>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyWindow:public QMainWindow
{
public:
MyWindow();
};

class MyWidget:public QWidget
{
public:
MyWidget();
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event);
};

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
Q_INIT_RESOURCE(puzzle);

QApplication app(argc,argv);

MyWindow mainWindow;

mainWindow.show();

return app.exec();
}

MyWindow::MyWindow():QMainWindow()
{
setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed));

QMenu * fileMenu=menuBar()->addMenu(QObject::tr("Options"));

QAction * restartAction = fileMenu->addAction(tr("NewGame"));

QAction * exitAction = fileMenu->addAction(tr("Exit"));
exitAction->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Quit);

QWidget * tempWidget=new MyWidget();

QFrame * newFrame=new QFrame();
QHBoxLayout * horizontal= new QHBoxLayout(newFrame);

horizontal->addWidget(tempWidget);
setCentralWidget(newFrame);
}

MyWidget::MyWidget():QWidget()
{
setMinimumSize(100,100);
setMaximumSize(1000,1000);
}

void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(this);
painter.drawPixmap(QRect(0,0,500,600),QPixmap("Board").scaled(QSize(500,600),Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,Qt::SmoothTransformation));
painter.end();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, it is  spelling mistake. actually it is slide bar

Comment: In the above code I am trying to show a picture in a window through a widget. But due to that windows size is smaller than picture, I need a scrollbar in the window to see the whole picture. But I didn't get6 any scrollbar in window. So thtat I am asking which function will set the scrollbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you paintEvent you are forcing the image to be painted to 500x600 pixels but you are not giving a fix size to the widget. So if the widget is smaller than that you cannot see the full image. If you do a setFixedSize(500, 600) it should fix your problem.

You are also doing

setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed));

in the main window. Are you giving a fix size apart from setting the size policy? If size policy is fixed you should specify a size for the window.

Also I think you can call setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed); directly.

Comment: Ya, it's working by changing the size of the window using setFixedSize. Is it possible to make the window which can adjust it's size according to the widget.
 And can you say how to make a widget which can adjust it's size according to the image it got.

Comment: But still I want to get a scrollbar

Comment: Hello, to adjust the widget to the image you just need to get the image size and set the widget size. Something like: widget.setFixedSize(image.size()). You can do that in a setBackgroundImage(const QPixmap&) method, this way it will adjust everytime you change it

Comment: What do you mean by the scrollbar? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: see in the above "code window" there is one vertical scroll bar, and one horizontal scroll bar. Like that I want to have those in my window or widget.

Comment: Why dont you use a QScrollArea as content for your MainWindow and use the QWidget with the fixed size of the picture as content for the QScrollArea. This should give you the scrolls you need.

Comment: @cnebrera thank you, it works. I think I will meet you again in some qt question